Problem with resolution on external monitor on Dell Inspiron 15-3511 (Ubuntu 24.04)
I'm having trouble setting a resolution higher than 1920x1080 on an external monitor connected to my Dell Inspiron 15-3511 via HDMI. I'm currently using Ubuntu 24.04, and while in Windows I can achieve 2560x1440 at 60Hz, in Ubuntu the maximum resolution available is 1920x1080.
Problem details:
My laptop has an Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] graphics card.
The external monitor is a Gigabyte G27QC and supports resolutions up to 2560x1440 at 144Hz.
The laptop's HDMI output is HDMI 1.4.
The xrandr command does not show the 2560x1440 option, even after adding the mode manually:
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "2560x1440_60.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "2560x1440_60.00"

When I run this last command, I get the error:
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

What I already tried:
I checked the drivers:
I'm using i915 as the driver.
I installed and reinstalled the xserver-xorg-video-intel package.
I checked the monitor capabilities with edid-decode, confirming that it supports 2560x1440.
I modified the /etc/default/grub file by adding the parameter:
video=HDMI-1:2560x1440@60

I updated GRUB and rebooted, but the problem persists.
I switched from Wayland to Xorg and back, without success.
I tried the latest kernel available via HWE.
Additional information:
Output of xrandr --verbose:
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm

...
Output of sudo lshw -C video:
*-display                 
 descripción: VGA compatible controller
 producto: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
 fabricante: Intel Corporation
 configuración: driver=i915 latency=0

Output of edid-decode:
I confirm that the monitor supports 2560x1440 at 60Hz, 120Hz, and 144Hz.
Could anyone help me?
I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to use 2560x1440 resolution on the external monitor, as I know the hardware supports it (tested on Windows). I appreciate any guidance or additional steps I can try.

i would guess its a incorrect modeline parameters.
lets try this
-Remove old line:
xrandr --rmmode "2560x1440_60.00"

-Generate new line:
cvt 2560 1440 60

then use previous command output:
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00" 312.25 2560 2752 3024 3488 1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "2560x1440_60.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "2560x1440_60.00"

if it it still does not work you can try to force it:
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "PreferredMode" "2560x1440"
EndSection

